# Tell java which keyboard to listen to

Tags: java, linux, keyboard

I have one keyboard plugged into a linux box and then I'm running my Java over ssh.  I want to know if there is a way to tell Java to listen for input from a specific keyboard/terminal.  Since the keyboard I want to capture is plugged into the physical machine and no user is logged in I'm not sure there is a way to do this, but I thought I might ask here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have root permissions you can read keyboard events directly from the keyboard device under `/dev/input`. Decoding the events will require a little effort but it can be done; you can read about the data format in [/dev/input keyboard format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662368/dev-input-keyboard-format).

This snippet reads keyboard events and recognizes which key A-Z you press and release:

```
    // replace path with path from your system
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
        new FileInputStream("/dev/input/by-id/usb-0430_0005-event-kbd"));
    String map = "    abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ";
    // sizeof(struct timeval) = 16
    byte[] timeval = new byte[16];
    short type, code;
    int value;
    while (true) {
        in.readFully(timeval);
        type = in.readShort();
        code = in.readShort();
        value = in.readInt();
        System.out.printf("%04x %04x %08x %c\n", type, code, value, 
                                                 map.charAt(value>>>24));
    }
```

Comment: If FileInputStream is not wrapped using BufferedInputStream, code throws java.io.IOException: Invalid argument. When code is DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
   new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/dev/input/by-id/usb-0430_0005-event-kbd"))); everything works correctly.

Comment: True, it seems that reading from /dev/input must be done into sufficiently large buffer (e.g. 16 bytes), so that entire event is read completely in one call. Reading into smaller buffer may throw IOException. You should just specify reasonable buffer size in new BufferedInputStream, like 64 bytes, otherwise you have wasted 8KB memory which is default BufferedInputStream size.